# Convert Excel Text to Time

Tags: excel, vba, string, date, time

I have to convert some formatted text to excel time, but I could not find a solution by myself.

Here are some examples of the input text and how it should be converted:

```
 - 1 Hour 14 minutes    ==> 01:14:00
 - 1 minute.            ==> 00:01:00
 - 1 Hour 1 minute      ==> 01:01:00
 - 2 minutes            ==> 00:02:00
 - 3 minutes 12 seconds ==> 00:03:12
 - 29 seconds           ==> 00:00:29
```

Observe that some times there are both minutes and seconds and some others only one of minutes/seconds, besides some times you find minutes (plural) and some others just minute (singular). Finally, some punctuation signs could be in the text some times.

The data is in a spreadsheet column and I want to extract the excel formatted time in a different column on the spreadsheet.

I've tried different versions of `TimeValue()` and `DateValue()` and some nested replace() all of them in a cell formula, but none of them worked for all cases.

Could you give me an idea or some advice on how to approach this problem?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Please show some existing code.  What caused the text time values? Can the source of the problem be changed to provide three(3) distinct numeric values Hr/Min/Sec?  Is this a one time conversion to Time, or are more rows expected to continue in the days to come?

Comment: Please check the output written for `3 minutes 12 seconds ==> 00:02:00`. Shouldn't it be `00:03:12`?

Comment: @Paul Vicioso one option i VBA code

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the late response, first VBA is not an option, that's why I did not include it as a tag. Second yes there is a mistake in the examples data: 3 minutes 12 seconds ==> 00:02:00 should be 3 minutes 12 seconds ==> 00:03:12. Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with your question for a day and see that others have done the same. I admire the solution offered by Ron Rosenfeld using FilterXML which I briefly considered and discarded as too outlandish. It isn't. But neitehr is it neat. For "neat" look no further than the UDF below. Call it from the worksheet with something like `=TextToTime(A1)` and be sure to format the cell you put this in as Time, perhaps like `hh:mm:ss`.

```
Function TextToTime(Cell As Range) As Double

    Dim Fun(2) As String
    Dim Txt() As String
    Dim Tmp As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Txt = Split(Cell.Value)
        For i = 1 To UBound(Txt)
            If Not IsNumeric(Txt(i)) Then
                Tmp = 0
                Tmp = InStr("HMS", UCase(Left(Trim(Txt(i)), 1)))
                If Tmp Then
                    Fun(Tmp - 1) = Val(Txt(i - 1))
                End If
            End If
        Next i

    For i = LBound(Fun) To UBound(Fun)
        If Fun(i) = "" Then Fun(i) = 0
    Next i

    TextToTime = TimeValue(Join(Fun, ":"))
End Function
```

This function is very versatile. It can translate strings like "5 hours 10 minutes 15 seconds" or "5 hours, 10 minutes, 15 seconds" (with commas) or even "5 hours & 10 minutes and 15 seconds". It needs the spaces around the numbers but doesn't balk at extra spaces or typos. It fails on "75 minutes and 66 seconds" but that could be dealt with if it's an issue. The key advantage of VBA is that almost anything can be dealt with using just a few extra lines of code. Worksheeet functions don't have that capability.

Comment: In the end, I convinced the client to use a macro, so I used this solution and it worked marvelously. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not include VBA as a tag, here are some formula solutions.

If you have Windows Excel 2013+ with the `FILTERXML` function, you can use the following:

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1)," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'hour')]/preceding-sibling::*[1]")/24,0)+
IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1)," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'min')]/preceding-sibling::*[1]")/1440,0)+
IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1)," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'sec')]/preceding-sibling::*[1]")/86400,0)
```

If you do not have the `FILTERXML` function:

- Create a named formula:

  - `Formulas` → `Defined Names` → `Define Name` → `New Name` → **seq_99** → `Refers to:` → `=IF(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,255,1))-1)*99)`

Then use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),-1+MATCH("hour*",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),0))/24,0)+
IFERROR(INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),-1+MATCH("min*",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),0))/1440,0)+
IFERROR(INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),-1+MATCH("sec*",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),0))/86400,0)
```

Algorhythm:

- Find the string `hour` or `min` or `sec`
- Return the node prior to each of those strings
- divide by the appropriate factor to create an excel time value

**Note:** Custom format column B as `hh:mm:yy`

[image]

As pointed out by @ScottCraner in the comments, the formulas can be shortened by creating an array formula:

Using `FILTERXML`:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1)," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,"&{"'hour'","'min'","'sec'"}&")]/preceding-sibling::*[1]")/{24,1440,8640},0))
```

without `FILTERXML`:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),-1+MATCH({"hour*","min*","sec*"},TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),0))/{24,1440,8640},0))
```

*In some earlier versions of Excel, you may need to "confirm" this **array-formula** it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar*

Comment: You could wrap in SUM the first formula: `=SUM(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1)," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,"&{"'hour'","'min'","'sec'"}&")]/preceding-sibling::*[1]")/{24,1440,8640},0))`  depending on version it would need CSE.

Comment: Same with second: `=SUM(IFERROR(INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),-1+MATCH({"hour*","min*","sec*"},TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),0))/{24,1440,8640},0))`

Comment: @ScottCraner Good point.  And I suspect that by using `SUMPRODUCT`, one can avoid the need for CSE.

Comment: Unfortunately the use of IFERROR would require the CSE regardless of SUMPRODUCT or SUM

Comment: @ScottCraner Hmmm. Didn't realize that.

Comment: That is of course if one does not have dynamic array formula.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can take this and edit it to suit your needs:

[image]

Here is the formula :

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND("da",A2,1),0)>0,LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)-1)*24,0)+IFERROR(1*MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)+1),FIND(" ",A2,FIND(" ",A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)+1)+1)-FIND(" ",A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)+1)),0*1)
```

I just wanted the date converted to hours so you can finish to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use VBA and you keep the same format in Column A you could use the below code:

**Code:**

```
Sub Converter()

    Dim i As Long, y As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim arrData As Variant, arrLine As Variant
    Dim Hours As String, Minutes As String, Seconds As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        arrData = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

        For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)

            Hours = "00"
            Minutes = "00"
            Seconds = "00"

            arrLine = Split(arrData(i, 1), " ")

            For y = LBound(arrLine) To UBound(arrLine)

                If InStr(1, UCase(arrLine(y)), "HOUR") > 0 Then
                    Hours = Right("0" & arrLine(y - 1), 2)
                ElseIf InStr(1, UCase(arrLine(y)), "MINUTE") > 0 Then
                    Minutes = Right("0" & arrLine(y - 1), 2)
                ElseIf InStr(1, UCase(arrLine(y)), "SECOND") > 0 Then
                    Seconds = Right("0" & arrLine(y - 1), 2)
                End If

            Next y

            .Range("B" & i).Value = Hours & ":" & Minutes & ":" & Seconds

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image]