# How to convert duration time in excel? (e.g.) 0h 31m 3s to 00:31:03?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to convert duration time in excel?

I need to convert duration from this format: `0h 31m 3s` to that format: `00:31:03`
Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your text 0h 31m 3s is in cell b2 you could use the following formula:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"h ",":"),"m ",":"),"s","")
```

And then set the format of Cell B2 to Time instead of General.

Alternatively if you don't want your time as a number but will accept it as text and you do not want to play with cell formatting you could opt to use the following which will give a text value result for the time:

```
=TEXT(--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"h ",":"),"m ",":"),"s",""),"hh:mm:ss")
```

A third option which is easier to understand when it is broken down into parts is to strip out the number for hours, minutes and seconds.  Then drop those formulas into the corresponding part of TIME(hours, minutes, seconds):

```
Hours
=LEFT(B2,FIND(" ",B2)-2)

Minutes
=MID(B2,FIND(" ",B2)+1,FIND("m",B2)-FIND(" ",B2)-1)

Seconds
=LEFT(RIGHT(B2,3),2)

Combined in Time
=TIME(LEFT(B2,FIND(" ",B2)-2),MID(B2,FIND(" ",B2)+1,FIND("m",B2)-FIND(" ",B2)-1),LEFT(RIGHT(B2,3),2))
```

Option 3 similar to option 1 returns a number for time which excel can work with much easier than text.  The key to getting it to display the way you want is setting the formating of the cell to time of use custom format HH:MM:SS.

[image: POC]

Comment: bah, I hate it when I get anchored on my first thought and then someone shows me I over thought it.  grumble...grumble...grumble.

Comment: @ScottCraner you had it buried in part of your formula from what I saw.   I am just not up and up on the filterxml and the office 2016 yet.  The nice thing is that there are many options on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Modified @RonRosenfeld answer from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61205753/4851590):

```
=SUM(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"h"," h"),"m"," m"),"s"," s"))," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,"&{"'h'","'m'","'s'"}&")]/preceding-sibling::*[1]")/{24,1440,86400},0))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Excel does not know the duration between timestamp and duration, both are the same:

When I enter "00:31:03" the cell formatting automatically becomes:

```
hh:mm:ss
```

When I change the cell formatting to:

```
hh\h mm\m ss\s
```

Then, the value becomes "00h 31m 03s".

You can turn this around as well, but you need to know that the latter formatting is not default recognised by Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the `SUBSTITUTE`s, if one has access to `TEXTJOIN` you could use:

```
=--TEXTJOIN(":",,TRIM(MID(" "&A1,FIND({"h";"m";"s"}," "&A1)-2,2)))
```

Which should then be a numeric value, automatically recognized as time and formatted as such.